# Derive generic type of a class from a specific factory method parameter value

Tags: typescript, generics

Is there a way in TypeScript to write a factory method that returns an instance of a generic class so that the specific type of the generic class is derived automatically?

In the example below, the factory method `create()` takes an enum value that decides with which generic type parameter the returned class is instantiated. However, the type of the property `value` is derived as `String|Number|Boolean`. Is it possible to make it clear to the compiler that the generic type is related to the `PropertyType` enum value, so that, in this case, the type of `value` would be `Number`?

```js
class Property<T> { 
    public value: T;

    public static create(propertyType: PropertyType) {
        if (propertyType === PropertyType.Text) {
            return new Property<string>();
        }
        else if (propertyType === PropertyType.Number) {
            return new Property<number>();
        }
        return new Property<boolean>();
    }
}

enum PropertyType {
    Text,
    Number,
    Boolean,
}

let prop = Property.create( PropertyType.Number );
prop.value = 4;
```

[image]

Comment: Please post code as *text*.

Comment: Note that the general answer of passing a type as a parameter looks like `public static create<T>(propType: new() => T): Property<T> {  return new Property<T>();  }`, it's unclear whether that meets your needs here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Unfortunately, this is legacy code I have to migrate. The general structure (method recieves enum value and derives a specific class) cannot be changed.

Comment: If you want someone to help you properly, please post your code as text as @jonrsharpe suggests.  Few people will be willing to spend the time and effort necessary to manually transcribe code from an image into their IDE.

Comment: @jcalz: I chose to use a picture intentionally since it shows that the compiler derives the union type. The question is just: why? I'd expect it to derive the specific type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't infer the mapping is because the compiler doesn't perform the type of analysis you're expecting.  If you inspect the type of the `Property.create()` function, it is:

```
Property<T>.create(propertyType: PropertyType): Property<string> | 
  Property<number> | Property<boolean>;
```

It infers that the function sometimes returns a `Property<string>`, and sometimes returns a `Property<number>`, and sometimes returns a `Property<boolean>`, so the return type is the union of all those.  I'm pretty sure it just sees the different `return` statements but doesn't do control flow case analysis to figure out which input values lead to which output values (which is impossible to do in general.)

---

So instead you need to explicitly tell it about the mapping.  The easiest way to do this is to use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) on `Property.create()`:

```
class Property<T> {
  public value: T;

  public static create(propertyType: PropertyType.Text): Property<string>;
  public static create(propertyType: PropertyType.Number): Property<number>;
  public static create(propertyType: PropertyType.Boolean): Property<boolean>;
  public static create(propertyType: PropertyType) {
    if (propertyType === PropertyType.Text) {
      return new Property<string>();
    }
    else if (propertyType === PropertyType.Number) {
      return new Property<number>();
    }
    return new Property<boolean>();
  }
}
```

Now if you call the function you will see what you expect:

```
let prop = Property.create(PropertyType.Number);
prop.value = 4; // inferred as number
```

---

There are other ways to do this.  You can use string literals instead of enums and store the mapping in a type:

```
type PropertyTypeMapping = {
  Text: string,
  Number: number,
  Boolean: boolean
}
type PropertyType = keyof PropertyTypeMapping;
```

Then you can represent `Property.create()` as a function which takes a `PropertyType` and [looks up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the key in `PropertyTypeMapping` to build the return type.  You can only look up string or number literals, and even though enum values are generally numbers or strings, they don't play very nicely with lookup types.  Here it is:

```
class Property<T> {
  public value: T;

  public static create<K extends PropertyType>(
    propertyType: K
  ): Property<PropertyTypeMapping[K]> {
    if (propertyType === 'Text') {
      return new Property<string>();
    }
    else if (propertyType === 'Number') {
      return new Property<number>();
    }
    return new Property<boolean>();
  }
}
```

Check that it works:

```
let prop = Property.create('Number');
prop.value = 4; // number
```

---

Hope those help.  Good luck!